# Find number of elements inside ng-repeat template, before I have any items in the array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are using AngularJS, and I have a server generated template like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='data in lazyContentFactory.items'>
    <my-element data="data[0]"></my-element>
    <my-element data="data[1]"></my-element>
    <my-element data="data[2]"></my-element>
</div>
```

Here, each item has a property data that is an array with dynamically set number of posts from the server. In this case I need to fetch 3 data-items from an API. This number may vary, depending on the settings on the server.

How can I find the number of "my-element" elements while lazyContentFactory.items have length = 0, so I know how many data items I need to fetch? The elements are not rendered in the DOM, so it seems I can not fetch them with angular.element.find, nor register them via directive compile pre or post functions.

Is this possible? Is my question clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned more about the way Angular executes code, I found a method you can call on modules called .run. These [run-blocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks) will be executed after all your services has been created, but most importantly in my case, before the DOM has been altered by Angular, and thus all my initial elements are accessible. In the run-block I could therefore count all my elements that would be hidden by the ng-repeat directive, before they are hidden!

NB: This is not optimal use of Angular, because I have to check the DOM for elements before Angular traverses the DOM. Maybe another framework could have been used, because we do need the flexibility on the back-end.

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
    .run(function (elementService, cacheService, myConstants) {
        var initialNrOfMyElements = elementService
            .getNrOfElementsInDomWithAttribute('my-element', 'some-attr');
        cacheService.put(
            myConstants.initialNrOfMyElements,
            initialNrOfMyElements
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rely on Angular! Use another `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat='data in lazyContentFactory.items'>
    <my-element ng-repeat='subdata in data' data="{{subdata}}"></my-element>
</div>
```

Here is a basic **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/nu4nc55v/11/)** showing it in action
Nesting `ng-repeat`'s is one of the areas where angular gets really really powerful

Comment: But I do not know how many data elements to fetch. The idea was to count elements in the template, and then fetch that number of data elements for each item.

Comment: Why do you need to count them beforehand? You are referencing them as members of an array `data[#]` so why not let Angular iterate through the items like it is designed to do?

Comment: The template is server-generated by a CMS, and to fill the template, I need to know how many posts to fetch from the data API.

Comment: That should probably be handled in the controller/data fetching ($http) logic and not the template HTML.

Comment: Sure, I just can't get a hold of the elements. That is my question. :) I am willing to use controller, factory, service or plain JavaScript if I can just count the number of "my-elements" inside the ng-repeat beforehand.